# Formatting numeric values in tibble with thousand separators gives error

Tags: r, tibble

```
library(tidyverse)

separator <- function(x){
  format(as.numeric(x), big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
}

x <- c(1000)
y <- c(1000)
z <- c(1000)
df <- tibble(x, y, z)

df[ , 2:ncol(df)] <- apply(df[ , 2:ncol(df)], 2, separator)
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Assigned data `apply(df[, 2:ncol(df)], 2, separator)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 1 row.
x Assigned data has 2 rows. 
i Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`? 
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Why does this happen? Why does the new data suddenly have 2 rows? It should just keep 1 row and add thousands separator, starting from the second variable to end.

If it's a `data.frame`, R doesn't complain and just does the job but not with `tibble`s. I know there are a few differences in `tibble`s and `data.frames`, but I couldn't find a reason why this happens.

Edit (pointed out by Ric S): The code works with `tibble`s, that have more than one row, but not with "one-row-`tibble`s".

Comment: If you have already loaded the `tidyverse` library, then why not do `df %>%
 mutate(across(everything(), separator))`?

Comment: True, i am not consistent with the pipe operator yet. But the thousands separator should start from second variable to end. It should leave the first variable out, because this often is of type character and the function would fail. ```df %>%  
  mutate(across(2:ncol(df), separator))```. This would be what i needed. Thanks. But it doesnt answer, why i am getting the error

Comment: You could do it like this: `df %>% mutate(across(2:last_col(), separator))`

Comment: As `df %>%
 mutate(across(-1, separator))` or if you want to apply it on just numeric variables `df %>%
 mutate(across(where(is.numeric), separator))`.

Comment: That's funny: I get the error only with one-row tibbles. If `df` has more than one row, your code works

Comment: @Ric S exactly, i experience the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *lapply*:

```
df[ , 2:ncol(df)] <- lapply(df[ , 2:ncol(df)], separator)
```

---

If you had posted the **full** error/warning message, it would be clear:

```
# Error: Assigned data `apply(df[, 2:ncol(df)], 2, separator)` must be compatible with existing data.
# x Existing data has 1 row.
# x Assigned data has 2 rows.
# i Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Then we can check if the assignment is compatible, i.e: *list* class:

```
is.list(apply(df[ , 2:ncol(df)], 2, separator))
# [1] FALSE
is.list(lapply(df[ , 2:ncol(df)], separator))
# [1] TRUE
is.list(df[ , 2:ncol(df)])
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to just apply the separator function to y and z columns, you could do this:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(y, z), separator)
```