# format all numeric columns with comma to seprate the v

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-science

I have a data table below.

how do I format all columns with variables with comma values?

I know of the scales package but if I use the scales package I won't be able to use the table for some calculating operations any longer

i want something that will still retain the table format type as numeric.

| Customers | telex | manay | players |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| babs | 3434323424 | 937387573 | 96222221 |
| bobs | 53545322 | 758464938 | 122134 |
| pint | 43 | 7453537384 | 223444 |
| red | 35435 | 624353 | 345654 |
| yello | 4567 | 44 | 334 |

I want the output to look like this table below

| Customers | telex | manay | players |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| babs | 3,434,323,424 | 937,387,573 | 96,222,221 |
| bobs | 53,545,322 | 758,464,938 | 122,134 |
| pint | 43 | 7,453,537,384 | 223,444 |
| red | 35,435 | 624,353 | 345,654 |
| yello | 4,567 | 44 | 334 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting numeric values in tibble with thousand separators gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050218/formatting-numeric-values-in-tibble-with-thousand-separators-gives-error)

Comment: This may solve it. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

format() does this.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  Customers = c("babs", "bobs", "pint", "red", "yellow"),
  telex = c(3434323424, 53545322, 43, 35435, 4567),
  manay = c(937387573, 758464938, 7453537384, 624353, 44),
  players = c(96222221, 122134, 223444, 345654, 334)
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(telex:players, ~ format(., big.mark = ",", scientific = F)))
```

But note that your data changes to type "character".

Comment: Is there a way I can convert it back to numeric without losing the comma?

Comment: scientific = F already indicates that this formatting is unusual. I am not aware of any method that leads to numeric values with thousands separator. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you 
I have re-ordered my script since the script will convert the data type tp character which is what I need, so the output will be my last script ...i can continue with other operations while the data type is in numeric 
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `scales::label_comma()` function. Note that the format for using this is `scales::label_comma()(x)` since a label function is generated *and then* you call it on your numerical vector.

As noted in similar answers above, this converts the column type to character. To convert back to number, you can use `readr::parse_number`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tibble(
  Customers = c("babs", "bobs", "pint", "red", "yellow"),
  telex = c(3434323424, 53545322, 43, 35435, 4567),
  manay = c(937387573, 758464938, 7453537384, 624353, 44),
  players = c(96222221, 122134, 223444, 345654, 334)
)
df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Customers      telex      manay  players
#>   <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 babs      3434323424  937387573 96222221
#> 2 bobs        53545322  758464938   122134
#> 3 pint              43 7453537384   223444
#> 4 red            35435     624353   345654
#> 5 yellow          4567         44      334

df_with_comma <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(telex:players, scales::label_comma()))
df_with_comma
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Customers telex         manay         players   
#>   <chr>     <chr>         <chr>         <chr>     
#> 1 babs      3,434,323,424 937,387,573   96,222,221
#> 2 bobs      53,545,322    758,464,938   122,134   
#> 3 pint      43            7,453,537,384 223,444   
#> 4 red       35,435        624,353       345,654   
#> 5 yellow    4,567         44            334

df_reverted <- df_with_comma %>% 
  mutate(across(telex:players, readr::parse_number))
df_reverted
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Customers      telex      manay  players
#>   <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 babs      3434323424  937387573 96222221
#> 2 bobs        53545322  758464938   122134
#> 3 pint              43 7453537384   223444
#> 4 red            35435     624353   345654
#> 5 yellow          4567         44      334
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatC`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.table::fread('Customers  telex   manay   players
babs    3434323424  937387573   96222221
bobs    53545322    758464938   122134
pint    43  7453537384  223444
red     35435   624353  345654
yello   4567    44  334')

df %>% 
  mutate(across(telex:players, ~as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  mutate(across(telex:players, ~formatC(., format="d", big.mark=",")))
```

Which gives:

```
  Customers      telex       manay    players
1:      babs         NA 937,387,573 96,222,221
2:      bobs 53,545,322 758,464,938    122,134
3:      pint         43          NA    223,444
4:       red     35,435     624,353    345,654
5:     yello      4,567          44        334
```

Comment: I noticed that it change the data type from numeric to character.
Is there a way I can change it back to numeric without tampering with the comma for further operations
Thanks